# Making PHP7.2 work under Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, php7, 19.10

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 and use it for Web Development, mainly with PHP frameworks.

We have a few projects that run php7.2 and php7.3. I got 7.3 installed however 7.2 doesn't exist?

I've added the PPA `ppa:ondrej/php` which got me php7.3, however installing php7.2 gives me the error

```
$ sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                                                                                                  
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                      
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                        
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                    
Hit:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease    
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease          
Hit:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                      
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan InRelease [20.8 kB]                              
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Fetched 20.8 kB in 3s (8,105 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
$ sudo apt install -y php7.2 php7.2-cli

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.2-sodium' for regex 'php7.2'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-thrift' for regex 'php7.2'
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-cli
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-cli'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-cli'
```

Has anyone been able to get 7.2 installed on Ubuntu 19.10, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Check this PPA `https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php`

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Check my latest updates to the post above. 

I tried adding that PPA, however, I still get the same errors.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` then try to install.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I ran that before and did it again. See post above for results. It still returns that "Couldn't find package" errors for php7.2

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz, it didn't work, I tried it too :(

Comment: What about `sudo apt search php7.2` do You have any results ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz, nothing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb70p.png

Comment: I get sudo 
```
apt search php7.2
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

Comment: I have also same problem in ubuntu 19.10. Looking for solution.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1262), so I'm voting to close as a bug report.

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks, for linking that github issue. This has been fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug with 19.10 and has been fixed. https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1262

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `/etc/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main
```